# Jquery is not working in duplicate row of table

Tags: jquery, html

jQuery is working fine in first row of table but after adding another row jQuery is not working.

For first row gross amount can be calculated but after adding another row jQuery for calculating gross amount stops working.

```
[Here][1] is my jsfiddle link.
```

Comment: Try to use jQuery [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically added element.

Comment: you should post you code.. so that we can understand and help you

Comment: Thnkyou Deepak Biswal
It works.

Comment: Removed unnecessary blockquote and tidied up.

Comment: Stackoverflow requires you add the code to your question. Do not use a hack to display a URL. Use snipplets or code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

For Newly added element you need to bind the click event again.
And there is also issue with the duplicate id's as you are not updating the ids for newly added rows , either update the ids or use class instead.

HTML :

```
<div style="margin:10%;">
    <table id="tb" class="table table-list table-striped" style="width:40%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>S.No</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Net</th>
                <th>Vat(%)</th>
                <th>Gross</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="row_div">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="title" class="input-medium" name="title" cost_class="title" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="cos" class="input-medium" name="cost" cost_class="cost_type" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="date_Picker" name="date1" date_class="date_type" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="des" class="test" name="description" description_class="description_type" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="net" name="Net" class="num1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="vat" name="Vat" class="num2">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="gross" name="Gross" class="sum">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:20px;"><a href="javascript:add_tr();">Add</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="javascript:remove_tr();">Remove</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS code :

```
$(function () {

    $(document).on("click", ".date_Picker", function () {

        $(this).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        }).datepicker("show");
    });
});

var intTextBox = 1;
//FUNCTION TO ADD File BOX ELEMENT
function add_tr() {
    if (intTextBox > 0) {

        intTextBox = intTextBox + 1;
        var contentID = document.getElementById('row_div');
        var newtr = document.createElement('tr');
        newtr.setAttribute('id', 'floorstrText' + intTextBox);
        newtr.innerHTML = "<td>" + intTextBox + "</td><td><input type='text' id=title" + intTextBox + " name=title" + intTextBox + " class='input-medium cost' cost_class='cost_type'/></td><td><input type='text' id=cos" + intTextBox + " name=cost" + intTextBox + " class='input-medium' cost_class='cost_type'/></td><td><input  name=date" + intTextBox + " type='text' class='date_Picker input-medium'  id=dat" + intTextBox + " date_class='date_type'/></td><td><input type='text' id=des" + intTextBox + " name=des" + intTextBox + " description_class='description_type' /></td><td><input  name=Net" + intTextBox + " type='text' class='num1 key'  id=net" + intTextBox + " /></td><td><input  name=Vat" + intTextBox + " type='text' class='num2 key'  id=dat" + intTextBox + " /></td><td><input  name=Gross" + intTextBox + " type='text' class='sum'  id=gross" + intTextBox + "/></td>";
        contentID.appendChild(newtr);
        addEvent();
    }

}

//FUNCTION TO REMOVE TEXT BOX ELEMENT
function remove_tr() {
    if (intTextBox != 0) {
        var contentID = document.getElementById('row_div');
        contentID.removeChild(document.getElementById('floorstrText' + intTextBox));
        intTextBox = intTextBox - 1;
    }
}

function addEvent() {
    $(".sum").click(function () {
        var net = $(this).parents('tr').find('.num1');
        var vat = $(this).parents('tr').find('.num2');
        var gross = parseInt(net.val() || 0) + (parseInt(net.val() || 0) * parseInt(vat.val() || 0) / 100);
        $(this).val(gross);
    });

}
$(document).ready(function () {
    addEvent();
});
```

Try this code or check this demo [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nitish1604/49sz06pp/9/)